# How to use model in query string for Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using a class model like below to hold the search data information,

```
data class SearchDataModel (
    var keyword: String? = "",
    var from: String? = "",
    var to: String? = "",
    var page: Int? = null,
    var sortby: String? = null,
    var orderby: String? = null,
    var itemsperpage: Int? = null
)
```

For posting data we can use the call,

```
@POST("/data/save")
fun saveData(@Body postData: PostDataModel)
```

How to achieve the same for query string something like the one below?

```
@GET("/data/search")
fun searchData(@QueryString searchData: SearchDataModel)
```

I'm trying to prevent having lots of parameter in the function and have an optional query string parameter.

Comment: I don't think that there is an alternate solution for this other than having all the parameters explicitly indicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use URL encoding and pass Map into query.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@GET("/data/search")
fun searchData(@FieldMap searchData: Map<String, String>)
```

Then have a method in your `SearchDataModel` to add properties to the `Map<String, String>` and pass it to `searchData` function.

```
data class SearchDataModel (
    var keyword: String? = "",
    var from: String? = "",
    var to: String? = "",
    var page: Int? = null,
    var sortby: String? = null,
    var orderby: String? = null,
    var itemsperpage: Int? = null

    fun toMap(): Map<String, String> {
        return mapOf(
            "keyword" to keyword,
            "from" to from,
            "to" to to,
            "page" to page,
            "sortby" to sortby,
            "orderby" to orderby,
            "itemsperpage" to itemsperpage
        )
    }
)
```

Use it like that: `searchData(searchData: yourData.toMap())`

---

Good luck :)

Comment: Hi @Tomas, I'm looking into [QueryMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html) and [FieldMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/FieldMap.html). Using either seems to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @QueryMap annotation of Retrofit2.

Service interface should be like that;

```
interface YourService {
   @GET("<yourEndPoint>")
   fun fetchYourThings(
       @QueryMap things: MutableMap<String, Any>
   ): Single<YourResponse>
}
```

model class;

```
data class Thing(
   val data: String,
   val data1: Int,
   val data2: Boolean,
) {
   fun toMap(): MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf(
       "data" to data,
       "data1" to data1,
       "data2" to data2,
   )
}
```

call your service from DataSource

```
class YourRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
   private val yourService: YourService,
 ) : YourDataSource.Remote {

override fun fetchThings(
    key: Things
): Observable<YourResponse> =
    yourService
        .fetchThingss(
            key.toMap(),
        ).toObservable()
}
```